# Euler angles -> 3D rotation matrix-> Euler angles with tensorflow-graphics

Tags: tensorflow, euler-angles, rotational-matrices

I'm trying to understand the transformation between *euler angles* and *rotation matrix*.
Simulating random matrix of euler angles and the transformed them into 3D rotation matrix and back to euler angles do not preserve the original euler angles.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.experimental.numpy as tfnp
import tensorflow_graphics as tfg 
tf.random.set_seed(5)
n = 10
euler = tf.random.uniform(shape=[n, 3], minval=-tfnp.pi, maxval=tfnp.pi, seed=0)
R = tfg.geometry.transformation.rotation_matrix_3d.from_euler(euler)
euler_ = tfg.geometry.transformation.euler.from_rotation_matrix(R)
print(tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.abs(euler - euler_)))
```

output:

```
tf.Tensor(1.5279251, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

However when repeating this transformation again, now with `euler_` instead of `euler` as input, yield identical euler angles (up to numerical precision)

```
R_ = tfg.geometry.transformation.rotation_matrix_3d.from_euler(euler_)
euler__ = tfg.geometry.transformation.euler.from_rotation_matrix(R_)
print(tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(euler_ - euler__)))
```

output:

```
tf.Tensor(6.417433e-07, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

My question is why in the first transformation the *euler* angle do not preserved while in the second transformation they do preserved?

Answer (score 0):

The point is that there are two valid solutions for decomposiotn a *rotation matrix* into two **different** *euler angles*.
For example the *yaw* angle of the two soultions is realted with [image] (since [image])
For more detail see this exclent summary [Computing Euler angles from a rotation matrix](http://eecs.qmul.ac.uk/%7Egslabaugh/publications/euler.pdf)